# Method in Coffeescript Class returns function instead of string

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, jasmine

I simply wanna call a function which returns a Url as a string from an inherited class which is dynamically build:

```
class @Api

  DEFAULT_API_VERSION: 'v2'

  constructor: ->
    @setVersion(@DEFAULT_API_VERSION)
    return

  setVersion: (version) ->
    @version = version if version?

  getVersion: ->
    @version

  baseUrl: ->
    "http://api#{@getVersion()}.mysite.com/api/#{@getVersion()}/"

class @ApiArticle extends Api

  constructor: ->
    super
    return

  articlesUrl: ->
   "#{@baseUrl}news/articles".toString()
```

This is the test in the parent class which is **PASSING**

```
  it 'provides the baseUrl for Api calls', ->
     api = new Api()   
     expect(api.baseUrl()).toEqual('http://apiv2.mysite.com/api/v2/')
```

This is my test and it **FAILS**

```
it 'returns all news articles url', ->
  new ApiArticle()
  url = api_article.articlesUrl()
  expect(url).toEqual 'http://apiv2.mysite.com/api/v2/news/articles'
```

The result I get from this spec, it should be a String but receives this:

```
 Expected
    'function () { return "http://api" + (this.getVersion()) + ".mysite.com/api/" + (this.getVersion()) + "/"; }news/articles'
 to equal
    'http://apiv2.mysite.com/api/v2/news/articles'.
```

Is there something missing? Do I have to explicitly render / calculate?

I am quite new to JS and Coffee.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
articlesUrl: ->
    "#{@baseUrl}news/articles".toString()
```

You wanted to call the method `baseUrl` in the superclass, but instead you only referred to it. So then the function itself gets `toString`ed, and "news/articles" is appended. This results in the string: `function () { return "http://api" + (this.getVersion()) + ".mysite.com/api/" + (this.getVersion()) + "/"; }news/articles`, which is what you see in the test error.

Fix it by actually calling `baseUrl`, not just referring to it:

```
articlesUrl: ->
    "#{@baseUrl()}news/articles".toString()
```

You can then remove the useless `toString` call.

You might want to consider renaming the method `getBaseUrl` to avoid making this mistake again.

Comment: Thank you, it works now also without the appended ```toString()```